# Can I use an external HD Camera to stream video?

Tags: video, streaming, webcam, camera

I have 3 cameras to choose form: a sony DSLR, a [Canon HR R500](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/camcorders/consumer/vixia/vixia-hf-r50) HD Camera, and [Canon XH A1](http://www.onequality.com/canon-xha1-hd-hdv-professional-camcorder-p-197.html)

I need to stream an event and a standard webcam won't do. I'd like to use one of my cameras to do this. I thought about getting a video encoder, hooking up the camera via hdmi, and using the USB3 output.

Is my idea viable? Is there a better solution?

Comment: The idea yes. USB3 for what? I did it very often, but few years ago when HDMI wasn't popular, so we use composite video or SDI interfaces (Sony Betacam SX). You will need a capture card for receive the video and a software for encode and stream, we used VLC and we were happy. You must take care your network connection (bandwith, firewalls, routing, etc.) and try different configurations (codecs, bitrates, etc.) Try from the client side how look the video (and the audio, of course).

Comment: Yes this depends well on your Network. If you were to have network issues the stream could go down. Best to Test the Scenario before doing the stream with the equipment you decide on.

Comment: Ok, so based on your responses I need my camera, a capture card, encoding software, and what I'm streaming to. Both Facebook and Youtube recommend Open Broadcast Software (which I have). Since this is a Macbook Pro I just need the external capture card.